# Oracle to MSSQL data migration is slow on INSERT

Tags: java, sql-server, oracle

I wrote a method that gathers data from an Oracle server, formats and encrypts the data then inserts it into a MS SQL server. The method moves about 60000 records and takes a bit long and is a little sloppy. Can anyone see places to clean it up and make it faster?

Two of the areas that I see might need improvements are when the result set is being added to the `List`. And when the `List` is being inserted 1000 rows at a time into the MS SQL table.

Here is the code:

```
public static void get_random_selection(Connection ora_conn, Connection sql_conn) throws Exception, SQLException{

    Statement sql_stmt = sql_conn.createStatement();
    Statement ora_stmt = ora_conn.createStatement();

    ResultSet sql_rs = null;
    ResultSet ora_rs = null;

    //Select the max QUARTER from RANDOM_SELECTION in MS SQL
    sql_rs = sql_stmt.executeQuery("SELECT MAX(QUARTER) FROM RANDOM_SELECTION");

    sql_rs.next();
    int max_from_mssql = sql_rs.getInt(1);

    ora_rs = ora_stmt.executeQuery("SELECT MAX(QUARTER) FROM RANDOM_SELECTION");

    ora_rs.next();
    int max_from_oracle = ora_rs.getInt(1);

    //If the max_from_oracle is larger than max_from_mssql than the AL's and RL's in Oracle
    //are fresher and need to be moved to MS SQL
    //if (max_from_oracle > max_from_mssql){
    if(1==1){

        System.out.println("The RANDOM_SELECTION table in Oracle is more up to date than the RANDOM_SELECTION table in MS SQL.");

        System.out.println("Retrieving RANDOM_SELECTION data from Oracle.");

        //select items from RANDOM_SELECTION and DROPPER_CITY_BRK_2 that need to be moved
        ora_rs = ora_stmt.executeQuery("select distinct(random_selection.randnum), " 
                            + "random_selection.quarter, " 
                            + "random_selection.ozip3, "
                            + "random_selection.boxid, " 
                            + "random_selection.boxaddr, " 
                            + "random_selection.locdesc, " 
                            + "random_selection.loccity, " 
                            + "random_selection.lastmf, "
                            + "random_selection.lastsat, "
                            + "random_selection.boxtype, "
                            + "random_selection.svcclas, "
                            + "random_selection.dropzip5, "
                            + "random_selection.dropper_id "
                      + "from random_selection "
                      + "where random_selection.dropper_id is not null "
                      + "and random_selection.quarter = " + max_from_oracle + " "

                  + "union "

                      + "select distinct(random_selection.randnum), "
                            + "random_selection.quarter, " 
                            + "random_selection.ozip3, "
                            + "random_selection.boxid, " 
                            + "random_selection.boxaddr, " 
                            + "random_selection.locdesc, " 
                            + "random_selection.loccity, " 
                            + "random_selection.lastmf, "
                            + "random_selection.lastsat, "
                            + "random_selection.boxtype, "
                            + "random_selection.svcclas, "
                            + "random_selection.dropzip5, "
                            + "dropper_city_brk_2.dropper_id "
                      + "from random_selection, dropper_city_brk_2, dropper "
                      + "where random_selection.ozip3 = dropper_city_brk_2.zip3 "
                      + "and dropper.dropper_id = dropper_city_brk_2.dropper_id "
                      + "and dropper.active = 1 "
                      + "and dropper_city_brk_2.dropper_id <> 10002 "
                      + "and random_selection.quarter = " + max_from_oracle + " "
                      + "and random_selection.dropper_id is null");

        System.out.println("Retrieved RANDOM_SELECTION data from Oracle.");

        List<String[]> random_selection = new ArrayList<String[]>();

        System.out.println("Assigning ResultSet to List.");

        while (ora_rs.next()){
            random_selection.add(new String[]{
                ora_rs.getString("RANDNUM"),
                ora_rs.getString("QUARTER"),
                ora_rs.getString("OZIP3"),
                ora_rs.getString("BOXID"),
                ora_rs.getString("BOXADDR").replace("'"," "),
                ora_rs.getString("LOCDESC") == null ? ora_rs.getString("LOCDESC") : ora_rs.getString("LOCDESC").replace("'",""),
                ora_rs.getString("LOCCITY").replace("'", " "),
                ora_rs.getString("LASTMF"),
                ora_rs.getString("LASTSAT").equals("11:58pm") ? "null": ora_rs.getString("LASTSAT"),
                ora_rs.getString("BOXTYPE"),
                ora_rs.getString("SVCCLAS"),
                ora_rs.getString("DROPZIP5"),
                ora_rs.getString("DROPPER_ID")});

            System.out.println(ora_rs.getRow());
        }

        System.out.println("Finished assigning ResultSet to List.");

        //leading statement for the following loop
        String query = "insert into random_selection "
                  + "(RANDNUM,QUARTER,OZIP3,BOXID,BOXADDR,LOCDESC,LOCCITY,LASTMF,LASTSAT,BOXTYPE,SVCCLAS,DROPZIP5,DROPPER_ID) VALUES";

        int jj = 0;

        //loop through random_selection_array creating an INSERT statement to insert 999 entries at a time
        //this is done to speed up the process
        for(int ii = 0;ii<random_selection.size();ii++){

            String[] array_holder = random_selection.get(ii);

            query = query
                  + "("
                  + "'"+array_holder[0]+"',"
                  + "'"+array_holder[1]+"',"
                  + "'"+array_holder[2]+"',"
                  + "'"+array_holder[3]+"',"
                  + "'"+array_holder[4]+"',"
                  + "'"+array_holder[5]+"',"
                  + "'"+array_holder[6]+"',"
                  + "'"+array_holder[7]+"',"
                  + "'"+array_holder[8]+"',"
                  + "'"+array_holder[9]+"',"
                  + "'"+array_holder[10]+"',"
                  + "'"+array_holder[11]+"',"
                  + "'"+new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(encrypt(array_holder[12]))+"'),";

            //every 999 iterations enter here
            if (jj > 998){
                //add |%| to the end of the string so that you can remove the final ','
                query = query+"|%|"; 
                query = query.replace(",|%|","");

                System.out.println(query);

                //sql_stmt.executeUpdate(query);
                query = "insert into random_selection (RANDNUM,QUARTER,OZIP3,BOXID,BOXADDR,LOCDESC,LOCCITY,LASTMF,LASTSAT,BOXTYPE,SVCCLAS,DROPZIP5,DROPPER_ID) VALUES";
                jj = 0;
            }
            jj++;

            //the last few entries will be added one at a time to prevent nulls records from being inserted
            if (ii > (random_selection.size() / 999) * 999){
                //add |%| to the end of the string so that you can remove the final ','
                query = query+"|%|";
                query = query.replace(",|%|","");

                System.out.println(query);

                //sql_stmt.executeUpdate(query);
                query = "insert into random_selection (RANDNUM,QUARTER,OZIP3,BOXID,BOXADDR,LOCDESC,LOCCITY,LASTMF,LASTSAT,BOXTYPE,SVCCLAS,DROPZIP5,DROPPER_ID) VALUES";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The client wants to refrain from any open connections between the two servers.

Comment: Or try this http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=16742 and pray it works like they say it does.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, profile the code to find the bottleneck.

Some other idea:

- Use threads. One thread retrieves the data from Oracle and one or more threads upload it to MSSQL.
- Use [PreparedStatement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099425/when-we-use-preparedstatement-instead-of-statement)s for inserting data.
- Disable indexes in MSSQL during the migration.

Some generic notes:

1. It's unnecessary to assign `null` to variables:

   ```
   ResultSet sql_rs = null;
   ...
   sql_rs = sql_stmt.executeQuery("SELECT MAX(QUARTER) FROM RANDOM_SELECTION");
   ```

   You could simply write this:

   ```
   ...
   ResultSet sql_rs = sql_stmt.executeQuery("SELECT MAX(QUARTER) FROM RANDOM_SELECTION");
   ```
2. Instead of the `String[]` array (whose indexes are [magic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29#Unnamed_numerical_constants)) I'd use a data object with named fields.

   ```
   public class RandomSelection {
       private String randNum;
       private String quater;
       ...

   }
   ```
3. Use the [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html).

   - `get_random_selection` should be `getRandomSelection`,
   - `ora_stmt` should be `oracleStatement`,
   - etc.
4. Split the method at least to two smaller one: one should handle retrieving and another one should create the `insert` statements.
5. Keep it [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), repeated codes should be moved to a new method.

   ```
   query = query+"|%|";
   query = query.replace(",|%|","");

   System.out.println(query);

   //sql_stmt.executeUpdate(query);
   query = "insert into random_selection (RANDNUM,QUARTER,OZIP3,BOXID,BOXADDR,LOCDESC,LOCCITY,LASTMF,LASTSAT,BOXTYPE,SVCCLAS,DROPZIP5,DROPPER_ID) VALUES";
   ```